# How to cache a simple XML file?

Tags: android, caching

I have a very easy question. I wan't to cache a file. I think the best way is a XML file. There are a lot tutorials how to cache a file, but I don't understand anyone. I wan't to make a XML file, if it doesn't exist. If the file exists I wan't to have the permissions to add XML atributes to it. I know this is a noob question, but I really don't know how I should do this. Could anyone tell me how?

I know this this is really bad English, but I hope you'll understand my question.

Answer (score 4):

XML doesn't cache. XML is a file standard. You can cache XML files, but XML has nothing to do with caching.

Caching is really just about keeping things around for easy reference. The idea is that if you are using something a lot, you want to keep it around for easy access. It's like books on your desk. You keep the ones you use a lot near you, while the ones you don't you keep on the book case across the room.

I also don't think you are really talking about caching here. You want to create an xml file if it doesn't exist. Ok, do you know how to do that? If you want to modify it if it does exist, than just check wherever you are creating the file to see if its there. If it is, load it and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading a XML from the web and storing it in a database as string.

You can retrieve it at any time and parse the string with

`Xml.parse(xmlString, new MyXmlContentHandler());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data then you are better off with [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for example.

Otherwise, if you want to retrieve and store data from/to an XML file, it would be best to read the current data on activity resume into an in-memory object, then do any modifications of the data to that object, and finally persist (write) the XML file from the object when the activity pauses. Don't write the XML file each time you want to change a single attribute.

But again, SharedPreferences might be better, depending on your use case.